FastHTML fail to load
When loading the fastHTML demo example the browser page for http://0.0.0.0:5001 shows invalid address:
This site can't be reached.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
Site might be temporarily down...

You fix this by changing the url in the browser to
http://localhost:5001


Instead of http://0.0.0.0:5001

The 0.0.0.0 is a wild card address.  simply use your machine name in there
http://my_machine:5001/
